# Take photo using camera on fragment and set to imageview below api level 22

Tags: java, android

Taking image using this but app crashes with fragment below api 22 and works well on above api 22

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: Please attach corresponding logcat error

Comment: Did you check intent with `intent.resolveActivity(..)` ?

Comment: Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.video.i', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.video.g.m

Comment: it gives this error the above and works fine after 22 and also with gallery intent

Comment: Weird error, try read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Camera) tutorial